# How to create a peephole in a door without a hole?

Tags: doors

the entrance door is without hole, but I would like to be with a peephole. How we can create this 
[image: Peephole]

Comment: Maybe if you explained more about your problem another solution might be suggested.  But I'm not aware of any "peephole" devices that don't require a hole to be drilled.

Comment: I mean is it possible just to drill a hole and create it or it should a new door be oredered

Comment: There are security cameras/doorbells that you can attach to the exterior of the door without the need to drill a hole.

Comment: That is a nice looking door , anything on it would take away its charm.  So many other options out there .

Comment: Try on the ceiling a smoke with camera in it..

Comment: @RobertMoody what is a “on the ceiling a smoke...”?

Comment: To Solar Mike   they make smoke detectors with spy cameras in them.

Comment: @Robert Oh so a "smoke" is a smoke alarm... A "smoke" is also a cigarette... just asking for clarity...

Comment: Trade slang .  Same as gfci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are renting, get the permission of the landlord or you might get charged for unauthorized modification considered to be damage. Some landlords might want to do the installation themselves.

Note that you generally buy the peephole and then follow the instructions for that peephole.

Some peepholes have a little cover on the inside that swings out of the way. Some peepholes give a sharp image at long distance focus and some require close focus. At age 74 I need 2.5 D reading glasses so I can tell the difference, but a young person might not detect any difference. Through some peepholes I get a sharper image with my readers on.

Comment: Also, if it's a fire door (which an apartment front door probably should be) any modification could invalidate its fire door approval.

Answer (score 2):

If when you say the door is without a hole, but you are allowed to drill one then it is a question of deciding the height and a suitable diameter.

If you cannot drill a hole then some sort of miniature camera will be needed...

When drilling a hole through the door, making sure you go through square is crucial and a tiny pilot hole then drilling from both sides gets a clean hole - at least in my experience.

Here is one possibility: [Peephole on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DVT97QW)

Comment: I liked the land lord comment and  needs to be a factor  .